# mobile screen game: 2 list of options

Tags: mobile, labels, games, organization

We have mobile game which includes 3 levels (training, public, expert), this game has 4 modes.

[image]

now we have added new modes for training mode, these new modes are related to Training level only, what should we do to keep good user experience and add new modes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the use cases?

1. New users
2. Existing users who went through the initial training but are now informed that there are new training modes.

Action: You need to show users (specifically existing users) that there are new modes. New users would not have known that there had been only one mode.

[image]

Once someone selects "Training" he can see a display of the different modes. (Whether it's a list or a card stack is up to you.)

Comment: I want to use same screen, but i want to add modes related to training level, also I don't want to make confusion with public and expert level whose different levels

Comment: can you help how should I display the list of modes?

Comment: That should be a new question which describes the UX issues that you're facing.